# Can someone explain to me this javascript based internal website search script?

Tags: javascript, html

Can someone explain to me line by line what is happening in this script ? :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function Gsitesearch(curobj){
var domainroot=curobj.domainroot[curobj.domainroot.selectedIndex].value
curobj.q.value="site:"+domainroot+" "+curobj.sitesearch.value
}

</script>
```

Thanks !

Comment: need to ask more specific questions and provide context for your function and objects passed into it

Comment: simple. it's whatever is written, since no one on this community will know that those variables hold we can only guess. WTF is curobj?

Comment: @bitoiu This is the google site search plugin, curobj is the form, domain root is the dropdown where you choose just this site or the internet, and q is the hidden dropdown google actually cares about.

Comment: if you had placed everything on the question maybe you wouldn't have two downvotes already.... @charlietfl said it well (more specific questions)

Comment: It's not an "internal" website search script, it's an external google search for pages internal to a specified domain (i.e. Google does all the work).

Comment: You ppl downvoted me without even understanding the question properly... . I wanted to know the strings inside <script> tag. What each of the thing does. Jesus, everyone here with megallomanic and sociopath syndrome ?

Answer (score 1):

It's from here:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/google_site_search2.shtml

The snippet, along with a `<form>` that submits to `http://www.google.com/search`, allows you to submit a search to google that limits results to those coming from the domain `domainroot`.

Full example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// Google Internal Site Search script II- By JavaScriptKit.com (http://www.javascriptkit.com)
// For this and over 400+ free scripts, visit JavaScript Kit- http://www.javascriptkit.com/
// This notice must stay intact for use

function Gsitesearch(curobj){
var domainroot=curobj.domainroot[curobj.domainroot.selectedIndex].value
curobj.q.value="site:"+domainroot+" "+curobj.qfront.value
}

</script>


<form action="http://www.google.com/search" method="get" onSubmit="Gsitesearch(this)">

<p>
<input name="q" type="hidden" />
<input name="qfront" type="text" style="width: 180px" /> <input type="submit" value="Search" /><br />
Search: 
<select name="domainroot">
<option value="www.javascriptkit.com" selected="1">JavaScript Kit</option>
<option value="www.dynamicdrive.com">Dynamic Drive</option>
<option value="www.freewarejava.com">FreewareJava.com</option>
</select>
</p>

</form>

<p style="font: normal 11px Arial">This free script provided by<br />
<a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com">JavaScript Kit</a></p>
```